# Ordernar o re-ordenar contenedores con sortable de JQuery

Tags: jquery, cookies

Bueno lo que estoy buscando hacer es que la posición del contenedor se guarde en una COOKIE, para que cada usuario pueda tener sus contenedores a su manera.

```js
$(function() {
  $( "#boxed" ).sortable({
    revert: false,
    opacity: 0.5
  });
  $( "#boxed, #small" ).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
.small{
    border: 1px solid #dad55e;
    background: #fffa90;
    color: #777620;
    height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="boxed">
    <div class="small">Item 1</div>
    <div class="small">Item 2</div>
    <div class="small">Item 3</div>
    <div class="small">Item 4</div>
    <div class="small">Item 5</div>
    <div class="small">Item 6</div>
    <div class="small">Item 7</div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de ante mano

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: hacer que la posición del contenedor se guarde en una COOKIE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

las Cookies normalmente tienen varias restricciones y su manejo es mayormente para identificadores. Por ejemplo quieres que un usuario no pierda la sesión durante 1 mes, usas una cookie con un valor aleatorio y lo guardas en la base de datos.

Los navegadores están siendo más estrictos con esto, así que te recomiendo local storage de JS.

Puedes guardar todo tipo de información con una escala mucho mayor.

Ejemplo para guardar el arreglo.

```js
//Declare vars
var MyList = {
    "0": {
        "txt": "Item 1"
    },
    "1": {
        "txt": "Item 2"
    },
    "2": {
        "txt": "Item 3"
    }
},
Html = '<div class="small"></div>';
if(localStorage.getItem("myList") != null){
    MyList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myList"));
}
else {
    saveLocalStorage();
}
//Rebuild List
reBuildList();
$( "#boxed" ).sortable({
    revert: false,
    opacity: 0.5,
    start: function(event, ui) {
        var start_pos = ui.item.index();
        ui.item.data('start_pos', start_pos);
    },
    change: function(event, ui){
        var start_pos = ui.item.data('start_pos'),
        index = ui.placeholder.index()-1;
        SavePos(start_pos, index);
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
    }
});
$( "#boxed, #small" ).disableSelection();
function SavePos(old, newPos){
    var saveData = MyList[newPos];
    MyList[newPos] = MyList[old];
    MyList[old] = saveData;
    saveLocalStorage();
}
function saveLocalStorage(){
    localStorage.setItem("myList", JSON.stringify(MyList));  
}
function reBuildList(){
    $("#boxed").empty();
    $.each(MyList, function(i,d){
        var ele = $(Html).text(d['txt']);
        $("#boxed").append(ele);
    });
}
```

```css
.small{
    border: 1px solid #dad55e;
    background: #fffa90;
    color: #777620;
    height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="boxed">

</div>
```

En este caso la lista se crea de forma dinámica con JS, los resultados son almacenados en un Objeto, allí podrás incluir toda la información adicional que desees.

1. Al iniciar el documento se pregunta si existe algo en nuestra variable local storage, para recuperar la información mediante JSON.parse, si no existe, le asignamos la actual.
2. Se llama la función sortable con las funciones start y change, start nos permite guardar la posición actual del elemento que vamos a mover, luego en "change" obtenemos esa posición y la posición en la que quedó nuestro elemento.
3. Usamos la función SavePos, esta solo altera el objeto, primero guardamos los datos de la nueva posición, asignamos la primera y luego asignamos la segunda con los datos guardados.
4. La función reBuildList, limpia el HTML que se encuentra dentro de "#boxed" y luego mediante un recorrido al objeto MyList, va asignando el texto que le corresponde. Aquí puedes adicionar toda la información adicional que necesites, como identificadores, nombres, etc.
5. Revisa el localstorage del DevTool de tu browser de preferencia, allí deberás encontrar la variable "myList" con la estructura, debe cambiar a medida que interactúas con tu lista.

OK, aquí va la edición:

1. Si lo llamas de la base de datos, deberás construir un array similar al que te dejo aquí.
2. Codificar el array para recibirlo en JS y decodificarlo.
3. El elemento .clone del HTML es muy interesante, te permite ver la estructura que necesitas para luego clonarla en JS.
4. En la función reBuildList(), se crea una variable "ele" que obtiene la estructura vacía del HTML para poderla modificar a tu gusto. Como te decía anteriormente, allí puedes adicionar lo que necesites, ya sea que venga de PHP o no.
5. Observa que clonamos el elemento .clone y luego lo eliminamos, nos es útil para evitar escribir HTML sobre JS. También se modifica el nombre de la variable LS para que no tengas problemas con la anterior.

No tengo idea de los datos que vas a manejar, pero te dejo lo básico para comprendas un poco más su manejo, luego de practicar un poco, harás cosas increíbles.

```js
//Get Array PHP 
var MyList = JSON.parse(window.atob('<?=$arrayJS?>')),
Html = $(".clone").clone();
//Delete small DIV 
$(".clone").remove();
if(localStorage.getItem("myList2") != null){
    MyList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myList2"));
}
else {
    saveLocalStorage();
}
//Rebuild List
reBuildList();
$( "#boxed" ).sortable({
    revert: false,
    opacity: 0.5,
    start: function(event, ui) {
        var start_pos = ui.item.index();
        ui.item.data('start_pos', start_pos);
    },
    change: function(event, ui){
        var start_pos = ui.item.data('start_pos'),
        index = ui.placeholder.index()-1;
        SavePos(start_pos, index);
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
    }
});
$( "#boxed, #small" ).disableSelection();
function SavePos(old, newPos){
    var saveData = MyList[newPos];
    MyList[newPos] = MyList[old];
    MyList[old] = saveData;
    saveLocalStorage();
}
function saveLocalStorage(){
    localStorage.setItem("myList2", JSON.stringify(MyList));  
}
function reBuildList(){
    $("#boxed").empty();
    $.each(MyList, function(i,d){
        var ele = Html;
        ele.find('.smallImgSrc').attr('src', d['image']);
        ele.find('.smallname').text(d['name']);
        ele.find('.smallTxt').text(d['txt']);
        console.log(ele);
        $("#boxed").append(ele.html());
    });
}
```

```css
.small{
    border: 1px solid #dad55e;
    background: #fffa90;
    color: #777620;
    display: flex;
    height: 45px;
}  
.smallTxt {
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    color: cadetblue;
}
.smallImg {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 8px;
}
.smallname {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    width: 80px;
}
.smallImgSrc {
    width: 35px;
}
```

```html
<?php 

$myListInfo = array(
    '0' => array(
        'txt'=>'Item 1',
        'name'=>'Pepito',
        'image'=>'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQj6m9qDpgBKwnxdGsen1OXMPtKYrmJR7V0MQ&usqp=CAU'
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'txt'=>'Item 2',
        'name'=>'Juan',
        'image'=>'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/51/f6/fb/51f6fb256629fc755b8870c801092942.png'
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'txt'=>'Item 3',
        'name'=>'Marta',
        'image'=>'https://www.shareicon.net/data/256x256/2016/09/15/829452_user_512x512.png'
    )
);

//Conver to JS 
$arrayJS = base64_encode(json_encode($myListInfo));
?>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="boxed"></div>

<div class="clone">
    <div class="small">
        <div class="smallImg">
            <img class="smallImgSrc" src=""></img>
        </div>
        <div class="smallname"></div>
        <div class="smallTxt"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok, me funciona, ahora como hago para agregarle el HTML o el PHP, para que se vea lo que quiero?